# Numerical Datatype Exported as Character Data in Excel (Teradata)

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm new to Teradata, when I created a table with a clearly defined data types for numeric data (column Loss), upon exporting through "Export the result set to an external column" as an .xlsx file, all numeric data type columns were converted to character by default. Is there any way to make it store as numerical value instead?

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE temp1, NO LOG
(Segment CHAR(10),
 MOB Integer,
 Loss DECIMAL(5,4)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS:

INSERT INTO temp1 (Segment, MOB, Loss)
VALUES ('SuperPrime',1,0.0023)

SELECT * FROM temp1
```

Comment: This is not a database question, really - it depends on the client tool you are using to export the data. For 5-digit precision you should be able to export as numeric; over 15 digits you either extract as text or lose precision. Some tools have options to control this, some do not.

Comment: I'm using Teradata Studio Express now, let me look into the preference settings and report back.

Comment: The default can be changed: Preferences > Teradata Datatools > Export: Excel Export Options. But any numeric over 15 digits will be wrong as Excel only knows Floats.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I was able to change the setting and got it exported as numbers/decimals.